# libgdal.so when using 2 architectures on jammy

Tags: 22.04, cross-compilation

I am trying to build/cross build for both arm64 and amd64 on my amd64 machine (22.04)

to do that I installed both arm64 libraries on my machine (I already had the amd64 installed)

it seems that libgdal.so is overwritten by the install of libgdal-dev:arm64
/usr/lib/libgdal.so is now arm64, and it breaks my amd64 build.
if I install libgdal-dev again I get the correct amd64 libgdal.so.

I do not have this problem with other libraries. for example libgeos++-dev.

what I am doing wrong?